# How to setup two vertical windows and open in the same folder before shutting down

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

I always have two vertical windows open on my dual screen setup. Is there a way of saving this configuration at shutdown of machine so that when I start the machine again, it not only opens up the two vertical windows but also opens in the last known folders I was using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done by Windows itself. I would suggest using [WILMA](http://www.stefandidak.com/windows-layout-manager/) by Stefan Didak. It is excellent for multi monitor window management.